# Custom Include / Regions are empty after upgrade to Tridion site 9.5 and DXA 2.2

Tags: dxa, sdl-tridion, dxa2.2, sites-9.5

We have custom includes as regions and all of their entities are empty after upgrading to Tridion Sites 9.5 and DXA 2.2. I don't know if the upgrade breaks some paths or config. I published the settings and all related components/pages to those includes.

Comment: Are these include regions (pages) empty just on the DXA site, as viewed in a browser? What's in the Content Delivery (broker) storage or on the Content Manager side (Template Builder or CM preview in the Classic UI)?

Comment: It appears the include regions are not included in the JSON result as well. The broker DB has the proper content and the UI displays the components correctly. When hitting the include page URL it also returns the correct content.

Comment: @AlvinReyes I read through the doc something about synchronizing pages and regions, is that relevant? https://docs.rws.com/816112/745071/sdl-tridion-sites-9-5-main-documentation/content-manager-functionality-introduced-in-------------sdl-tridion-sites-9-1

Comment: Alvin, the page model JSON does have the include region info in Template Builder.